# Converting a dictionary to a CSV file using concatenation

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, concatenation, delimiter

[image: Constructing a CSV]

In the image above is an example of a dictionary can be converted to a csv file using concatenation however I am having difficulty understanding the syntax of constantly repeating the csvString variable in the for loop

I tried to do a similar thing by importing the csv module but I have been tasked with understanding how this can be done manually to simply output the csv file in your ide

Comment: the `csvString` variable starts of as an empty string. Inside the for loop data is being concatenated to the variable, resulting into a fully csv formatted string. `endLine` or `\n` creates a new line.

Comment: to understand `+=` see https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/addition_assignment.html

Comment: You can step through the code in your IDE and see how the string changes. As a note, this is an expensive way to write a file. Each `+=` creates a new string and copies all of the data. This copy grows as the `csvString` gets larger. Some of those parens are not needed: `csvString += key + delimiter` would do.

Comment: Please post the code as text in a code block, not an image.

Comment: Adding to @tdelaney: It might *seem* okay on the CPython reference interpreter, in many cases, because it has a (brittle) optimization to minimize how often copies actually occur when you perform repeated concatenation like this. But it's a brittle optimization (something as simple as `sys.stdout.write(csvString)` in the loop can inadvertently break it, depending on implementation, OS, runtime setup, and data-dependent details), and it doesn't apply on any other interpreter. It wouldn't be quite so bad if they were only building a line at a time, but building the whole file makes it terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how this code works. Each entry in the dictionary will make become a row in the csv file

for each key of the dictionary:

1. initiate the `csvString` with the given key and add the delimiter. So far the `csvString` is `"p1,"`.
2. load the value for the given key
3. add the first item of the list `details` and the `delimiter`. For the first key it'll be `"Takeshi Tanaka,"`. The `csvString` becomes `"p1,Takeshi Tanaka,"`.
4. add, as a string using the `str` function, the second item of the list `details` and the `delimiter`. For the first key it'll be `"25,"`. The `csvString` becomes `"p1,Takeshi Tanaka, 25,"`.
5. add, as a string using the `str` function, the third item of the list `details` and the `delimiter`. For the first key it'll be `"1.73,"`. The `csvString` becomes `"p1,Takeshi Tanaka, 25,1.73,"`.
6. add the fourth item of the list `details` and the `endLine` character to the `csvString`. The `csvString` becomes `"p1,Takeshi Tanaka, 25,1.73,Tokyo\n"`.

You could now add a line in the `for` loop to write the `csvString` to a csv file. Running the loop would add a row for each entry to your file

Answer (score 0):

`+=` means add the right-hand part to the left-hand part and replace the left-hand part with the sum.  It makes `a = a + b` a little more succinct: `a += b`.  It works with numbers (a true sum), and in this case strings (a concatenation).

```py
line = ''
line += 'Alice'
line += ' Cheng'
line += ', 47,'
line += ' Mailing Svcs'

print(line)  # Alice Cheng, 47, Mailing Svcs
```

Please also consider this relatively simple way to construct and print a CSV.

I modified the data so that the last column contains *commas as data* that need to be quoted (to actually be proper CSV):

```py
import csv, sys

people = {
    "p1": ["Takeshi Tanaka", 25, 1.73, "Tokyo, Japan"],
    "p2": ["Lisa Penny", 32, 1.69, "London, England"],
    "p3": ["Lorenzo Dubois", 38, 1.84, "Paris, France"],
}

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for id_, details in people.items():
    writer.writerow([id_] + details)
```

I get that maybe the exercise is just to print some "debug values", but the title of the code says *Constructing CSV* and the only way to **properly** construct a CSV (not introduce your own encoding errors that you, or someone else, will have to deal with later) will be to use a CSV-aware tool like [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: OP said they used the csv module but were tasked with understanding the exiting code.

Comment: @tdelaney, yes, thank you. I believe I understand the point of the exercise and OP's question.  I also read the title of the exercise and see the need to clarify that a side effect of the exercise might be a misconception about "constructing CSV" files. I've seen many such questions here on SO where teachers try to teach some principle of programming by hand-crafting CSV files, and I also see a lot of questions arising from improperly encoded CSV files or misunderstanding of CSV encoding.